# php indexed array manipulation and filtering

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array manipulation/situation that I cannot figure out. In a nutshell:

Get a string such as:

```
$testString = 'John doe 123 Main st 77555';
```

I am trying to get things split up to be 3 main parts such as:

```
$fname = 'John';
$lname = 'doe';
$address = '123 Main st 77555';
```

Currently I am exploding the array as such:

```
$splitTestString = explode(" ", $testString");
```

which gives me the string inside an array.

I've tried a for loop to go through the exploded string:

```
for($i = 0; $i <= count($splitTestString); $i++) {
  $fname = $splitTestString[0];
  $lname = $splitTestString[1];
  if(is_numeric($splitTestString[2])) { //take into account 2 last names
    $newAddress = $splitTestString[2];
  } else {
    $lname .= ' '.$splitTestString[2];
  }
}
```

But I am not sure how to get the address after the initial numbers all into its own variable. Another string example:

```
$testString = 'John doe smith 123 main st 77555';
$fname = 'John';
$lname = 'doe smith';
$newAddress = '123 main st 77555';
```

The user would be instructed to enter the information in the above format of first name, last name, address and zip code.

This is my first question out of all the searches I've done on here and please let me know if I've not followed the rules properly. I'm just at my wits end on this problem and cannot seem to find a solution to this situation. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do everything in a single loop, you should come up with a process for populating the name variables until you hit a word that starts with a number (is this really a safe assumption though?), then simply join the remainder into the address.

If possible, you should go back to the drawing board and provide a way for the user to provide the information in separate fields.

```php
$testString = 'John doe smith villalobos garcia navarro 123 Main st 77555';
$parts = explode(' ', $testString);

// Don't assume we will always have a first or last name, there could be only an address
$fname = '';

// Set up a buffer for the last name words
$lnameBuffer = [];

// Process input buffer until we hit a part that begins with a number
while(!is_numeric(substr($parts[0], 0, 1)))
{
    // Shift the next word off of the buffer
    $currPart = array_shift($parts);
    
    /*
     * If we don't have a first name yet, set it
     * Otherwise, append the word to the last name buffer
     */
    if(empty($fname))
    {
        $fname = $currPart;
    }
    else
    {
        $lnameBuffer[] = $currPart;
    }
}

// Join the last name buffer to populate the $lname variable
$lname = implode(' ', $lnameBuffer);

// The rest of the input buffer contains the address
$newAddress = implode(' ', $parts);

echo 'fname: '.$fname.PHP_EOL;
echo 'lname: '.$lname.PHP_EOL;
echo 'newAddress: '.$newAddress.PHP_EOL;
```

You could however achieve this much more easily using regex.

```php
$testString = 'John doe smith villalobos garcia navarro 123 Main st 77555';

preg_match('/([^\s]\S+)\s([^\d]*)(.*)/', $testString, $matches);

$fname      = $matches[1];
$lname      = $matches[2];
$newAddress = $matches[3];

echo 'fname: '.$fname.PHP_EOL;
echo 'lname: '.$lname.PHP_EOL;
echo 'newAddress: '.$newAddress.PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! I wish I could go back to the drawing board on the input, however this current process involves the user texting the information from their phone which hooks into our system. It was decided for the user to text in this way vs texting each individual piece of information needed.

Comment: @JeromeDelaCruz what Rob said, you _really_ should separate the inputs, because any splitting attempt will eventually hit edge cases you haven't accounted for. Why not have your users text e.g. `John#Doe#123 Street` in a single message then, so you have separators in place and no ambiguity is introduced in interpreting the input.

Comment: @MarkusAO we are actually testing it with commas such as John, Doe, 123 Street
However you can imagine how many errors we are getting from people not putting commas in the correct places thus negating this automated process we are creating. The thought here being what if we just have them enter the information without commas, can we capture the correct info and continue with the user experience.

Comment: I understand, Jerome Dela from Cruz 123 Avenue, or Jerome Dela Cruz from 123 Avenue. Or even Jerome from Dela Cruz 123 Avenue, if you have one name only. Or John Doe from 3rd Outback Street 345, or John Doe 3rd from Outback Street 345. If you only handle addresses that _always_ start with a number, or have clear edge cases that you can accommodate, you can split name/address. Otherwise, you can't accurately tell apart even multiple first and last names, much less so the person's names from the street names. Unless you back this up with surname and street name dictionary lookups.

Answer (score 0):

If your string is always formatted like "firstname lastname everything else is the address" you can just pass `explode` a limit like so:

```php
$str = 'John doe 123 Main st 77555';
$parts = explode(' ', $str, 3);
var_dump($parts);

//array(3) {
//  [0]=>
//  string(4) "John"
//  [1]=>
//  string(3) "doe"
//  [2]=>
//  string(17) "123 Main st 77555"
//}
```

If you need to split with a rule like 'the first time we see a number indicates the start of an address' you can just find that and split the string up like so:

```php
$str = 'john doe smith 123 fake street paris france';
$matches = [];
preg_match('/[0-9]/', $str, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
$numberPosition = $matches[0][1]; // this is the first matching element, and its position

$left = trim(substr($str, 0, $numberPosition)); // left side of the found number
$right = trim(substr($str, $numberPosition));   // right side of the found number

var_dump([
  $left, $right
]);

//array(2) {
//  [0]=>
//  string(20) "john doe smith"
//  [1]=>
//  string(26) "123 fake street paris france"
//}
```

Comment: @Gavin...I definitely agree with that option, but what about the other part where a user has "2 last names" such as "Doe Smith" or like my last name "Dela Cruz"?

Comment: you'll need to come up with specific rules that you know your strings look like. if you know the address will always start with a number you can split it there, added an example of this.